# PHP 5.2.6 to 5.3.3 update issue

Tags: php

My index.php page is a basic system that I wrote from the ground up.

my PHP looks like this:

```
session_start();
require_once('includes/config.inc.php');
require_once(ADMIN_CLASSES.'dbconnect.class.php');
$message = '';
$dbconn = new DBConnect();
$adminData = $dbconn->selectQuery('SELECT * FROM admin_users');
```

From this I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.

however if I remove all coding from the page and change it to `<?php echo "hi" ?>` it works fine....

Comment: Did you try Testing the code line by line? I mean, delete all but the first line, if it works, add the second line and so on until it crashes.. that will give you a clue of the problem

Comment: Are your <br> copy&past issues or are they realy in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your web server's error log file and it should tell you what file and line is generating the error.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like Chrome gives you this error. You have a wrong syntax some where in your file.

Try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
flush();
```

to your starting of code. Most probably your DB driver might have failed to load.

Comment: Analyse ur code for missing colons or something. Better you can use some IDE's for it als.

Comment: With the above... its working now... weird :D loving it though

Comment: now here is the kicker!!
When I do my facebook setup for my app, this appears:
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

Undefined index: code in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/votepoll/index.php on line 10 Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?....
code is blank!!!!